# How to add TXT record using dnsruby

Tags: ruby, dns

I am trying to add a TXT record using dnsruby library. What could be the best implemetation?

below is the sample code i am trying.

```
require 'dnsruby'

key = "mydns key"
resolver = Dnsruby::Resolver.new("dnsserverip")
update = Dnsruby::Update.new("zonename")
resolver.tsig = "update.zone", key, 'hmac-sha512'
update.add("domain.com", "TXT", 300, "This my txt content")
response = resolver.send_message(update)
puts response.answer
```

Comment: What you did till now?

Comment: I have updated the sample code.